# C# & SQL Server Insert Performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I've been working on a custom data layer for an application written in C# and I have a few concerns regarding performance.

Note 1: This is not an attempt to perform bulk inserts but rather an attempt gauge the potential concurrent throughput. Using a bulk insert from whichever framework is not currently an option. If I were to do data imports - this would be the route I would take.

I am doing a simple insert to a record about 2500 times to gauge the records inserted per-second. I reuse the same object for the insert each time to reduce the overhead here and I am now pre-generating the statement that actually does the insert. The pre-generated statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO "dbo"."account" ("accountnumber", 
  "address_city", "address_line1", "address_line2", "address_line3", 
  "address_postalcode", "address_province", "address_region", "name")
OUTPUT INSERTED.id
VALUES (@accountnumber, 
  @address_city, @address_line1, @address_line2, @address_line3, 
  @address_postalcode, @address_province, @address_region, @name);
```

My original data structure had used a `Dictionary<string, object>` and it passed through another helper function to apply the parameters with values to the DbCommand. To reduce this overhead I had converted it to a `Tuple<string, object>[]` instead. Both of these improvements, pre-generating the SQL statement for inserting and the Tuple object, increased the performance by about 20%. Which is fantastic; however, the baseline performance that being achieved was in the ballpark of around 80-100 record inserts per second so the improvement yielded around 120 records per second.

To delve into this a little more - the first tests are entirely synchronous and all contained within one transaction. I had to break out the connection code in order to test this directly. In addition, one connection is being used. So a combination of all of these factors only yields 120 records/s is concerning whereas direct on the SQL server I can get 2500 records/s.

For the next set of tests I do this entirely async within one transaction. The end result lands me in the 600-900 records/s range. Which is a huge improvement over the standard sync insert. I do understand that the sync nature of the original test would be slower but I didn't expect it to be this drastic of a change.

Finally to my question. Should I pursue an application with the sync insert methods and retain an easier architecture to develop or should I use the async methods and find a way to make it work within the application? Are there any potential improvements that any of you, the audience, can recommend? Next is related to the transaction - should I use `TransactionScope` instead of creating the transaction from the `DbConnection`?

This is what the async code looks like:

```
using (var dConn = dataContext.GetConnection())
{
    using (var transaction = dConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var statement = ... code that pregenerates the sql insert statement ...
        var waitable = new List<Task<object>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < records; i++)
        {
            var command = dConn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = statement;
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.ApplyParameters(record);

            waitable.Add(command.ExecuteScalarAsync());
            count++;
        }

        while(true)
        {
            if (waitable.Where(t => t.IsCompleted).Count() == waitable.Count()) break;
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep 50ms ...");
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

This is what the sync code looks like:

```
using (var dConn = dataContext.GetConnection())
{
    using (var transaction = dConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var statement = ... code that pregenerates the sql insert statement ...
        var command = dConn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = statement;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        command.ApplyParameters(record);

        for (int i = 0; i < records; i++)
        {
            command.ExecuteScalar();
            count++;
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}

sw.Stop();
```

[11/13/2016] Update:
I've done some additional testing and eventually converted the core data layer of the application to .Net Core 1.0.1. Initial test results are very promising. I am getting around ~1500 records/s without transactions, ~4500 records/s with transactions and ~6500 records/s with async calls and transactions.

Comment: You could try Entity Framework BulkInsert: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/ using a datatable you can import the data much quicker then if I remember correctly. As depending on your statement, which layer you use and whatsoever is very dependent on how fast the import goes (obviously).

Comment: The actual use of the application would be for any number of end users to use. I am just testing the throughput of my current code. I could use some sort of bulk insert, entity framework or even the Sql BULK INSERT but it isn't applicable in this situation.

Comment: For your `TransactionScope` question, I would be careful with it. There are restictions on it that don't apply to `dConn.BeginTransaction()`. for example a default timeout of 60 secconds is applied to the scope, if you don't finish your work in 60 seconds you get a exception thrown and your transaction rolled back. Also if the transaction spans multiple requests you may need to require that the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is running correctly on the client machine for the transaction scope to work. Neither are "problems" just stuff you need to be aware of.

Comment: Why are you generating the same command for each record? Just use the same command with different parameters. Another 100x improvement would come from batching multiple INSERT statements and only calling the database once 5-10 times, instead of 2500. The network round-trip eradicates any other delay

Comment: Finally, you should use the asynchronous versions of all commands to reduce blocking but *NOT* try to execute multiple commands asynchronously. It's not SQL Server that's slow, it's executing multiple commands when only 1 (BULK INSERT) or a few would be enough. You'll simply increase contention if you execute multiple single-record inserts concurrently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For the Async code it requires that I create a new command for each request. For the matter of parameters - I am using one  static set of data to remove the differences from the inserts. In terms of batching the requests - would it be possible to do something like - capture x number of insert requests in the system - if the batch is greater than y - execute the batch OR if the batch life is greater than 1s - execute the batch. The ultimate goal is to gauge individual insert performance rather than batch performance.

Comment: *Don't* create a new command for each request. In fact, this benchmark doesn't say anything for real-world scenarios - individual web server requests are concurrent already. What does matter for real scenarios is indexing, sufficient memory, storage and filegroup placement. Right now, you are simply measuring the overhead of your test code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The async code gives an error if I do not create a new command. If you notice - the sync code uses the same command.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and as I explained it simply obfuscates things. You are still measuring your overhead, and the network roundtrips. If you care about throughput, the sync version is irrelevant (what's the point of using only 1 client when you want to measure 100 concurrent ones?).

Comment: Which question are you trying to answer with your benchmarks? You need to answer that before deciding which scaffolding to use.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good point. I think i'll need to rethink my test. I'll continue the approach from the async perspective and when the code is at a more relevant testing point - i'll resume the testing. Which framework would you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127308/discussion-between-travis-sharp-and-panagiotis-kanavos).